# Does SQLCMD have a way to access it's input filename

Tags: t-sql, sqlcmd

SQLCMD can be run interactively and therefore it doesn't always have an input file but when it does, is there any way to access its name?  I don't see one documented but it wouldn't be the first time I just couldn't find something.

For example:

```
Print 'Executing $(ScriptPath)';
-- or
insert into Log(Path) values ('$(ScriptPath)');
```

Comment: Could you add the file name also as a variable with the `-v` parameter?

Comment: I don't 'own' the job that performs the execution and even if I did it would be a maintenance issue to insure the values were in sync with no way to tell they weren't.